# How to fix duplicated output of jq flattening JSON array

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to flatten a JSON file by using jq command. But the output got duplicated.

Please see my jqplay here: https://jqplay.org/s/gwvMIH_fed

My input JSON:

```
{
  "cost": 0.0,
  "interval": "0:01:00",
  "namespace": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
  "resourceregion": "australiaeast",
  "timespan": "2019-05-22T00:00:00Z/2019-05-22T00:02:00Z",
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "/my-api/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/Capacity",
      "name": {
        "localizedValue": "Capacity",
        "value": "Capacity"
      },
      "resourceGroup": "my-group",
      "timeseries": [
        {
          "data": [
            {
              "average": 15,
              "count": null,
              "maximum": null,
              "minimum": null,
              "timeStamp": "2019-05-22T00:00:00+00:00",
              "total": null
            },
            {
              "average": 16,
              "count": null,
              "maximum": null,
              "minimum": null,
              "timeStamp": "2019-05-22T00:01:00+00:00",
              "total": null
            }
          ],
          "metadatavalues": []
        }
      ],
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
      "unit": "Percent"
    }
  ]
}
```

My expected output:

```
{
  "apiId": "/my-api/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/Capacity",
  "metrics": "Capacity",
  "timestamp": "2019-05-22T00:00:00+00:00",
  "value": 15
}
{
  "apiId": "/my-api/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/Capacity",
  "metrics": "Capacity",
  "timestamp": "2019-05-22T00:01:00+00:00",
  "value": 16
}
```

Could anyone please have a look at the provided jqplay URL and advise.

Comment: What's worse is if there are two items in the values array and only one in every other: https://jqplay.org/s/0K5a0Jrnao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each .[] is like a "for" loop, so the multiplicative behavior you observe is essentially the result of having nested for loops.  It would seem that what you want is closer to:

```
.value[] as $v
| $v.timeseries[].data[] as $d
| {"apiId": $v.id,
  "metrics": $v.name.value,
  "timestamp": $d.timeStamp,
  "value": $d.average }
```

With your JSON as input, this produces two JSON objects, though the second of these differs very slightly from what you give as the expected output.

Comment: Thanks Peak. That is exactly what I need. I posted the jqplay URL for a working version: https://jqplay.org/s/YIJYWjzszB